F# async expressions using HttpClient
This example is taken from dotnet/fsharp documentation and it's outdated for this reason - "This construct is deprecated. WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/async-expressions
How would this example look using HttpClient?
Just to mention I'm new to web development but I do understand what async expressions are, just having trouble converting the example to be using HttpClient.
open System.Net
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions

let urlList = [ "Microsoft.com", "http://www.microsoft.com/"
                "MSDN", "http://msdn.microsoft.com/"
                "Bing", "http://www.bing.com"
            ]

let fetchAsync(name, url:string) =
    async {
        try
            let uri = new System.Uri(url)
            let webClient = new WebClient()
            let! html = webClient.AsyncDownloadString(uri)
            printfn "Read %d characters for %s" html.Length name
        with
            | ex -> printfn "%s" (ex.Message);
    }

let runAll() =
    urlList
    |> Seq.map fetchAsync
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore

runAll()


Here is some code from one of my projects.
You may want to deal with errors differently, but I guess you can extract what you need.
EDIT: I also added some simple error handling and made the example complete.
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Web =

    let private http = new HttpClient(Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds 40.)

    type WebError =
        | HttpErrorCode of HttpStatusCode * Body: string
        | HttpNetworkIssue of string
        | HttpTimeout

    let getStringAsync (url: string) =
        async {
            try
                let! response = http.GetAsync url |> Async.AwaitTask
                let! body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                if response.IsSuccessStatusCode then return Ok body
                else return Error (HttpErrorCode (response.StatusCode, body))
            with
                | :? System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException -> return Error HttpTimeout
                | ex -> return Error (HttpNetworkIssue ex.Message)
        }

module Test =

    let urlList = [ "Microsoft.com", "http://www.microsoft.com/"
                    "MSDN", "http://msdn.microsoft.com/"
                    "Bing", "http://www.bing.com"
                ]

    let checkSite (name, url:string) =
        async {
            let! res = Web.getStringAsync url
            match res with
            | Ok html ->
                printfn "Read %d characters for %s" html.Length name
            | Error (Web.HttpErrorCode(code, body)) ->
                printfn $"ERROR: http error code {code} with body {body}"
            | Error (Web.HttpNetworkIssue(s)) ->
                printfn $"ERROR: network issue: {s}"
            | Error (Web.HttpTimeout) ->
                printfn $"ERROR: timeout"


        }

    let runAll() =
        urlList
        |> Seq.map checkSite
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> ignore

    runAll()


If you want to do more than understanding the example, you may want to look at the existing F# http libraries that wrap HttpClient. You can easily find them by searching for "F# http".

I will. Thanks!
